# Regex - replace a combination of number and string with another string

Tags: php, jquery, regex, replace

I need to replace all occurrence of [any number] and [particular string] with a [replacement string]

For example if strings like **195 apples** or **10 apples** are found in a paragraph I need to replace this with **10 Oranges**

Example paragraph: There are 195 apples in the first basket and 10 apples in the second basket.

After applying regex replace, I should get a result
Result :  There are 10 Oranges in the first basket and 10 Oranges in the second basket.

In Jquery i used

```
 myString.replaceAll("[(?i)string]", "anotherstring");
```

Need to do this in PHP as well as Jquery.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

PHP

```
$re = '/(\d+\s((apples\b|apple\b)+))/';
$str = '195 apples in the first basket and 0 apple but 1 applex';
$subst = '10 Oranges';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

JQuery

```
var text1 = "10 apples is good";
var rrr = "10 Oranges";
var str = "There are 195 apple in the first basket and 10 apples in the second basket.1 apple";
var result = str.replace(/(\d+\s((apples\b|apple\b)+))/ig,"10 Oranges");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```js
 
 var myString = 'There are 195 apples in the first basket and 10 apples in the second basket.';
myString = myString.replace("/(?i)\d+\s+apples\b/g", "10 Oranges");
console.log(myString);
```

Comment: @user4826347: Yes, it is ;(, could you edit your question and add the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Search `\d{1,}\s+(apples)`

Replace `10 Oranges`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(\d+\s(\w+))
```

** *you can replace `\w+` with your desired string*

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/6YVtoT/2)

**JavaScript**

```js
var str = "There are 195 apples in the first basket and 10 apples in the second basket.";
var result = str.replace(/(\d+\s(\w+))/ig, "10 Oranges");
console.log(result);
```

**PHP**

```
$re = '/(\d+\s(\w+))/';
$str = 'There are 195 apples in the first basket and 10 apples in the second basket.';
$subst = '10 Oranges';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thought it worked first. It did not... Here is the thing, it is considering every words not just apples. if it has 10 strawberries, they are being replaced as well

Comment: @user4826347 just replace ' \w+ ' with `apples`